# Find out Scala Version Used to Make JAR

Tags: scala, jar

I'm trying to figure out which Scala version was used to compile `A.jar`. I have two versions: one from my ivy2 repo, and the other from Maven.

After running `jar -xf A.jar`, I grepped for `scala` and `version`, but found nothing:

```
$grep -ri scala *
$grep -ri version *
```

So, based on an unzipped* `JAR`, how can I determine which version of Scala was used to compile it?

*unzipped = run `java xf <name of jar>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what Scala version a .class file was compiled with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311355/how-can-i-tell-what-scala-version-a-class-file-was-compiled-with)

Comment: @SethTisue - I understand that my question can be answered by your link. But I suppose checking which Scala version a JAR uses boils down to finding out which version was used to make the `class` files?

Comment: Yes, because a JAR is really just a ZIP archive containing some classfiles. But yeah, I guess your question is a little different, and the answers here so far add value, so I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only convention I am aware of, is to put the version of scala in the name of the jar, for exemple : `scala-stm_2.9.3.jar`. 
But this is a convention ;-)

Now, if the name doesn't follow that convention, get any "class" file from the jar and run the `javap` command on if, cf: [How can I tell what Scala version a .class file was compiled with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311355/how-can-i-tell-what-scala-version-a-class-file-was-compiled-with)

Comment: This JAR does not include a version name.

Comment: Yes, thanks. So I suppose checking `any` `.class` file would not work if the JAR contained Maven modules whose pom files specified different compile versions? [Note - it's most likely not the case for me, but I want to make sure I understand why it's `any` class file]

Comment: Well, normally, for a given jar, only one version of scalac is used. And given compatibility issues across Scala versions, I recommend you to keep it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BuildInfo plug-in](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) to generate a small bit of code that includes the Scala version.