# What Version Of Kotlin Was Used To Compile This Jar?

Tags: kotlin

Given a jar file that I know was compiled with kotlin, how do I determine which version of kotlin was used to compile the class files in it?

If I do the following I get 52 (i.e. JDK8)

```
javap -cp target.jar -verbose fully.qualified.class.name | grep major
```

That is the java target version though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you *can*, given that (as far as I know) the Kotlin compiler doesn't store any version information in generated classes.

Unlike e.g. Scala, which [embeds its major and minor version in the compiled class files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323977/7366707), Kotlin only adds [`@Metadata`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816521/is-the-format-of-the-data-held-in-kotlin-metadata-documented-anywhere) annotations to methods and classes etc. to hold information about nullability, mutability, etc. You can find the protobuf for this information [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ee50aec7342ab375a105bb318e6501135e859028/core/deserialization/src/descriptors.proto).

You could use the older "standard" (which was also used in Scala projects) of [embedding the version in the JAR's name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295305/7366707).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to obtain the version of Kotlin used to **compile** the sources, but that doesn't really matter anyway. The more useful information is the **metadata version**, as that indicates compatibility with consumers of that Kotlin code.

When a newer compiler is used to generate code in [compatibility mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compatibility-modes.html) with the `languageVersion` and `apiVersion` [compiler flags](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#language-version-version), the code is usable in older versions as well.

The `languageVersion` defines source compatibility and causes the generated code to use the specified metadata version, and the `apiVersion` ensures that the code generated by the newer compiler is only using features of the stdlib available to the specified version.

Use the [Kotlin metadata printer](https://github.com/Guardsquare/kotlin-metadata-printer) to analyze an apk, jar, zip, or class file and print out the metadata information, which includes the Kotlin metadata version.

Here is some example output:

```
package foo.bar

/**
* Kotlin file facade (metadata version 1.9.0).
* From Java class: foo.bar.FooKt
*/

// Functions
...
```

Indicating that the metadata version of this class file is 1.9.0, and this code is only usable by Kotlin 1.9+.