# ClassFormatError: Illegal class modifiers in class ... 0x209

Tags: java, imap, myeclipse

I have a few some strange issues with my class after migrating from **JDK5/Tomcat5** to **JDK6/Tomcat7** both with **MyEclipse 9**.

Whenever I try to access 'myclass' via `jsp:usebean` I got following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class modifiers in class myclass: 0x209
```

The rest of log points nowhere. By trial and error I have trimmed huge class to the following problematic part:

```
 ...
 rf = store.getDefaultFolder();
 f = (IMAPFolder)rf;  
 final IMAPStore storeNew = store;
 Object val = f.doCommand(new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() { <-- problem propably starts here
 public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p)
throws ProtocolException {
 ...
```

The next strange thing is that my colleague is using the same environment with no problems. I have compared our class files and the only difference is in last but one byte. My class ends with '02 09', his '06 09'

After several days I am out of options how to get rid of it.

EDIT:

I have reinstalled/updated to MyEclipse 9.1. No luck so far.

Comment: Sure that JDK5 isn't lurking about somewhere and being accidentally used?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832241/java-illegal-class-modifiers-exception-code-0x209

Comment: is *myclass* a class that you've written/compiled or something from a third party lib?

Comment: @pst: Yep, I have checked it several times. It is most logical explanation, but still I am failing to solve it.

Comment: Andreas_D: Thanks, I have already checked this question several times as well :-)

Comment: @Andreas_D *myclass* is not third party lib

Comment: `0x209` is `public static interface` while `0x609` is a `public static abstract interface` ... does it make any sense? Right now I'd blame the compiler that is part of MyEclipse 9...

Comment: @Andreas_D No interfaces or abstract modifiers. Agree, I try to reinstall/update to MyEclipse 9.1

Comment: Please post an answer with your solution section - so that it is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

After another day trying to reproduce problem with a new project with a single file in it, I have realised that only remaining difference is in project/properties/java build path/libraries. There was J2EE 1.4 Libraries in the main project, so I have replaced it. After adding Java EE 6 Libraries voila. I am able to compile and run w/o any problems